# Timeout for Kubectl exec

Tags: kubernetes, timeout, kubectl

How can I set the timeout for the kubectl exec command ?

The below command does not work

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name bash --requrest-timeout=0 -n test
```

Comment: is there any error message?

Comment: I don't get any error message

Comment: your command is correct. The only thing we know nothing about is your `Pod`. Could you describe it?

Comment: What kind of information do you need to help me ?
It is pod create by stateful set

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is going on with `kubectl`, i have been using k8s for 2 years and i don't remember any situation, when `kubectl` returns nothing, not once has this ever happened. You've just provided only the command your trying to use. Its syntax is correct. The similar command is working in my environment. How anybody can help you?

Comment: So I execute below command:
`kubectl exec -it pod-0 bash --request-timeout=120s -n test`
and I get to the container shell, `root@*****:/opt/...`
and after some time when I do nothing in shell, throws me out of the shell

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo, try:

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name bash --request-timeout=0 -n test
```

See [kubectl official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) about request-timeout

```
--request-timeout string           The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests. (default "0")
```

Note that "0" is already the default.

Comment: So why after some time throws out of pod ?

Comment: by default it doesn't actually throw you out of a pod. As far as i understand; the timeout is for the kubectl command itself. once executed, you are linked to the pods process

Comment: so this command set the period of time after which throws me out of pod ?

Comment: no; once connected to the pod your kubectl command does not time out anymore

Comment: @Webber But I still get out of pod if there has no operation in several hours.

Comment: @gemfield if you are looking at logs, you should be using a logging backend. If you really want to keep the command line open in the pod for that long you will have to open an issue with kubernetes themselves. This is out of scope of this answer.

Comment: @gemfield it sounds like your actual problem is that kubectl simply disconnects after some time, without showing an error, and with exit code 0? That's what I'm seeing quite often, and I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue standing up an on-prem instance of K8s.  The answer in our situation was haproxy.

**If you have a load-balancer in front of your K8s API (control-plane), I'd look at a timeout on that as the culprit.**

I believe the default for haproxy was 20 seconds so after I changed it to 60m, we never noticed the problem again.